# Show all the results in solr textual query

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search

I have the following simple query in solr in which I want to solr all the records based on their name similarity to a text ("Olive Tasting Room"):

query: name:"Olive Tasting Room"

But when I search it on solr it returns only one document which is most similar. this is while I want a sorted list of all my documents based on their rank (similarity to my query).

how should I do this in sorl/lucene ?

Comment: So what do you mean by "Similarity"? Any document containing any of the words?

Comment: No I mean the default similarity of lucene:       score(q,d)   =   coord-factor(q,d) ·   query-boost(q) ·   
V(q) · V(d)
–––––––––
|V(q)|
  ·   doc-len-norm(d)   ·   doc-boost(d)

Comment: That's the score calculation - my point being that "Similarity" can mean a lot when you're trying to explain your problem. I've given an answer based on using each term as it has been written, which is the default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `field:"Term Term2" syntax, you're doing a phrase search - i.e. you expect the terms to come in succession after each other.

The best way to handle more "natural" queries is to use the `edismax` query parser. You do this by using `defType=edismax` in the URL. After changing to edismax, you can enter the query itself in `q` - `q=Olive Tasting Room` (escape it properly if you enter it directly into an URL), and `qf=name` (qf is short for "query fields", which fields the edismax handler should query).

You can also use the `pf3=text` parameter to give a boost to any documents that feature three words from your query after each other (and `pf2` for just two) in the text.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Mats!, I tried edismax but it doesn't work well because either because it give me too many false positive when I'm searching for similar objects! so basically what I want is to parse the query(which is a short phrase of at most 10 words) and search it in the "name" field of my documents. as you said I don't want the orientation of words effect the similarity score, and at the same time I wanna make sure that I'm not producing many false positives.

Comment: You can use the `mm` parameter to tell Solr how many terms that have to match - and you can use a percentage, so giving it `mm=50%` requires that at least half of the words are present. You can tune this to give more relevant results, and if you use the `pf` parameters you should be able to show the most relevant results on the top